# How can I create text file with the structure below this in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

this is the structure of CamVid 1.0 annotation from cvat. I have a folder with more than 1000 images that i need to put in that structure

it's basically `folder1_path/filename_XX.jpg` `folder2_path_filename_XX.jpg`

in my case it should be something like this after completed:

```
./original/DSC_0006.jpg originalannot/DSC_0006.png

./original/DSC_0007.jpg originalannot/DSC_0007.png

./original/DSC_0008.jpg originalannot/DSC_0008.png

./original/DSC_1000.jpg originalannot/DSC_1000.png
```

the dot in front is just because stackoverflow won't let me post without a indent warning

Comment: I do not understand. So `folder2_path_filename_XX.jpg` or `originalannot/`? What is the content of the folder? How does the content of the folder correspond with the file content you want to create? `the dot in front is` So you want with the dot or without?

Comment: In bash, you can use *brace-expansion*, e.g. `for i in {0006..0010}; do printf "folder1_path/filename_%s.jpg folder2_path_filename_%s.jpg\n" "$i" "$i"; done` or you can simply use a counter and the `%04d` conversion specifier instead -- up to you. (copy and paste the `for` loop into your terminal to try it)

Comment: Welcome to  stackoverflow! Please consider that this is not a "free support" website. Next time post, which solutions you have tried and what did not work for you, so we can learn from each other ;)

Answer (score 0):

By the power of SHELL and SED and FIND!

```
$ mkdir original ; touch original/DSC_{000{6.jpg,7.jpg,8.jpg},1000.jpg}
$ find -type f  | sed 's:.*:& &:; s:original/:original-not-:2'
```

output:

```
./original/DSC_0006.jpg ./original-not-DSC_0006.jpg
./original/DSC_0007.jpg ./original-not-DSC_0007.jpg
./original/DSC_0008.jpg ./original-not-DSC_0008.jpg
./original/DSC_1000.jpg ./original-not-DSC_1000.jpg
```

The first expression `s/.*/& &/` replaces "everything" with "what was previously found" two times + a space in between.

The second expression `s/foo/bar/2` changes *the second* occurrence of foo to bar.